# How to use multiline feature in the Jupyter Console

Tags: console, ipython, jupyter, multiline

Multiline feature in jupyter console would be great to use. I've searched in several sources, and they all say to use ctrl-enter or alt-enter but none of them work. Also read it's a bug that hasn't been fixed. Am I missing something (perhaps trivial)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is *multiline editing*:

- hold down **CTRL** and click in different places of the same cell;
- hold down **ALT** and drag down your mouse.

Answer (score 0):

\ at end of line works.  You may need to type enter twice to exit the multiline block.

I have noticed that \ at end of line does not work when the jupyter console is invoked from Emacs so make sure you work in plain terminal.